# Unable to access nested files in static resource

Tags: visualforce, managed-package, static-resources

I have a zip file containing images as a static resource. After repackaging the zip and uploading a new copy I'm no longer able to access the contents from VisualForce pages.

I access the image like this in the VF page:

```
<apex:image url="{!URLFOR($Resource.Doc_images, 'image.png')}"/>
```

That worked fine originally, but after updating the zip the image can no longer be found. The static resource is there and I can download it from `<server>/resource/<id>/MyNamespace__Doc_images`. The downloaded zip is not corrupted and appears to have the right files inside.

But `<server>/resource/<id>/MyNamespace__Doc_images/image.png` is not found.

Did anyone experience this before, and is there a solution / workaround?

Comment: Is there a namespace difference in the patch org which might cause it?

Comment: Found the answer -- I forgot that I had repackaged the files after creating the patch, and in the process I created a zip with a root folder, whereas the original zip did not have one. I'm editing the question to properly describe the issue

Comment: I was going to suggest that.  I'm doing that all the time when I work with Static Resources.

Answer (score 3):

Turns out when I repackaged the zip I created it with a root directory, for a structure like this:

```
Root/image.png
...
Root/image-n.png
```

whereas the original had a flat list:

```
image.png
...
image-n.png
```

So of course the files were no longer found. Obvious in retrospect -- but I'll leave the question up in case it helps someone who makes the same mistake...